# Table producers is not specified in the ABI {"table":"producers"}

Tags: nodeos, cleos, node, single-node

I'm so close. I ran ./nodeo --delete-all-blocks and it cleared up an error I was having previously and there's one command I can now run in CLEOS by myself without piggybacking off of a block producers node. But I'm still getting some errors regarding an ABI...here's what it looks like...

This is the result I get...

> FC Exception encountered while processing chain.get_producers: 3060003 contract_table_query_exception: Contract Table Query Exception
>
> Table producers is not specified in the ABI
>   {"table":"producers"}

I was trying to run **./cleos --url http://localhost:8888 system listproducers** and that's the response it gave me. I tried running BIDNAMEINFO as well and got the same result.

When I ran GET ACCOUNT this is the result I get...

> STD Exception encountered while processing chain.get_account: unknown key

I've added the plugins to the NODEOS config.ini file in my ROOT directory and when I ran --delete-all-blocks BNET started up and it said "START THREAD," so I know I'm close. At least I feel like I am lol. Just not sure where to go next.

Comment: Please be more obvious as to what you're trying to accomplish here, are you running your own single node test net and trying to query producers registered on your own system? Or are you trying to connect to the main net?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to the mainnet (I guess now I have to get v.1.0.5) and run NODEOS without any test errors (I have 4 test errors out of 35...one of which is NODEOS_TEST_RUN) so that I can develop on EOS and be able to test smart contracts and make sure they're built properly.

Comment: Or would you say using public nodes from Block Producers is fine for testing smart contracts?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not trying to connect to the main net which is a production EOSIO network with 21 block producers with BP's like EOS New York, Canada, etc.

If you're trying to run a single node test net I highly recommend using the Docker image that's provided by Block One, it's fantastic for development purposes and if you screw anything up you can just restart the Docker instance and you get to start fresh too, nor worry about resource allocation.

I would not recommend deploying test contracts on the main net as you'll waste resources and run into hurdles you simply wouldn't face on a test net.

Give the [Developers Portal](https://developers.eos.io/) from Block One a crack, checking out the [Docker](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart) section.
If you're not sure about Docker, learn it, will save you time in the long run.